# How to programmatically set 'created_by' when creating a new category

Tags: development, mvc

While writing an import script, I need to create categories for the data, and am successfully accomplishing that with the below code.  However, I can't determine how set the `created_user_id` column of the table.

The script is not logging in, but the `created_user_id` is always ignored, creating the category record with 0.

**UPDATE** Originally asked about `path`, but added ->rebuildPath()` - still no luck with the created_user_id

```
function createCategory( $title, $parent_id, $note=null ) {
    $table = JTable::getInstance('category');
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['parent_id'] = $parent_id;
    $data['extension'] = 'com_content';
    $data['published'] = 1;
    $data['created_user_id'] = 123456;
    $table->setLocation($data['parent_id'], 'last-child');
    $table->bind($data);
    if ($table->check()) {
        $table->store();
        $table->rebuildPath($table->id);
        // Success
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the problem, we used $app->login() before saving.  This seemed to be the cleanest answer for our situation, as a great number of other category and content items were being added at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`JTableCategory` sets that property in the store function, so you will have to do a bit of a hack to get it to work.

You can either set the user that you want the id to be in the session:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);
$session->set('user', $user);
```

Literally just add that in place of this line: `$data['created_user_id'] = 123456;`. It should then automatically get set for the `created_user_id`.

---

Alternately, you would have to run the store twice like this:

```
$table->store();
$table->created_user_id = 123456;
$table->store();
```

The category table class only sets the created_user_id if it is a new object. The first store creates the record in the database and will store the id back in `$table`. Then you can reset the value that you want and store again. (Note that this way will then set the `modified_time` and `modified_user_id` incorrectly...)

Comment: Setting the $session user didn't seem to do the trick, and the double store might have worked, but we changed the code to use the $model->save() and it caused all the content plugins to be fired twice.